# how do I find the position of a specific character in a character vector in r

Tags: regex, r

I have `x = c("AU|30|3020","AU|15|1510","AU|2000|510")`.

If I want to know the position of the last “|”  for each element in x, how do I do it. The answer should be 6 6 8.

An acceptable alternative is to find the position of (say) the second "|"  for each element (as opposed to last "|").

Comment: Perhaps something like `lapply(gregexpr("|", x, fixed = T), tail, n = 1)` is helpful?

Comment: I used sapply(gregexpr("|", x, fixed = T), tail, n = 1) and it worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the position of the last `|` (independent of the total number of `|`s) with the following command:

```
unlist(gregexpr("\\|[^|]*$", x))
# [1] 6 6 8
```

Answer (score 0):

are there always 2 `|`? if so

```
unlist(lapply(gregexpr("\\|",x),"[[",2))
```

otherwise you may need workaround. Also, look at `stringr` package